# Why use ng-file-upload Upload service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, multer, ng-file-upload

How come I have to use the Upload service with ng-file-upload like this

```
Upload.upload({
    url: '/postMyFormHere',
    data:   {
        fileToUpload: model.file,
        someField1: model.field1,
        someField2: model.field2,
    }
})
```

and can't just simply do

```
  $http({
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        url: '/postMyFormHere',
        data: {
            fileToUpload: model.file,
            someField1: model.field1,
            someField2: model.field2,
            }
    })
```

I thought ng-file-upload just enables binding of files from file inputs to the model.
Can't Angular natively do a multipart/form-data POST request ?

**Edit**:

I've been trying to make my multi-part post work via $http.
I changed the header  to :

`"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypEvyJj8BAuq4lk7T"`

But I get this error on my express server

```
Error: Multipart: Boundary not found
```

I'm assuming that the whole point of the Upload service is that it parses the POST payload with the multy part boundary right ?

Comment: The code is available [on github.com](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and has fairly good documentation...

Comment: You need to send your data as FormData object and set the Content-Type to `identity`. You can view the `Upload.upload()` code and see how it is being sent. Basically it takes care of content-type, creating form data, allowing resumable upload, enabling progress event, allowing abortion of the upload `abort()`, renaming the file, and some other features.

Comment: And as Mikki mentioned it allows uploading for IE8-9 using Flash and FileAPI shim.

Comment: very helpfull Mike

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can, the purpose of all modules which are created to handle uploading of files is browser support. IE10+ only support `FormData()` object. So, in case you need to support old browsers you need to solve this using `<iframe>` strategy, or just use existing libraries, which are basically doing the same.

**UPDATE**

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', model.file);
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})
```

Try this way!

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it will help you!